# Cloud Build service account not created when API enabled - Cant deploy app

Tags: gcloud

I am having issues deploying an update to a current app which was last deployed in July 2019.
It asked me to enable Cloud Build.
I had to first enable billing account for the app.  I did this.  I then enabled the cloud build API.
I now get a permission denied error when I run gcloud app deploy.  The docs say to check the service account permissions, but when I load that page it says I need to enable the Cloud Build API.  I click on the link and it shows me that the API is enabled.  I click manage, go settings, and it says "The Cloud Build API needs to be enabled before changing the permissions of the service account."

Answer (score 0):

Usually enabling an API takes few minutes before you can use it. Can you try again deploying your app?

Additionally, you don't need to add any new permission to your cloud build service account unless you are using cloud build in some kind of CI/CD pipeline. in That case you need to ⁠add some few [more permissions to this service account](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions).

You can always check which APIs are enabled using ⁠[gcloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/list).

I'd suggest try to disable and re-enable the API, wait for a few mins and try again.

**UPDATE**:

The issue described might be a result of a known issue.

I suggest you star this [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/153364908) to stay updated.